# How to get the env vars I want with the superuser command?

Tags: linux, sudo, opensuse, su

I'm running OpenSuse 12.1 KDE. I was previously running Ubuntu. In Ubuntu there was a superuser option (`sudo -s`) that preserved the original user's `HOME` env var (and another option, `sudo -i`, that set the target user's `HOME` env var).

I want to have the same functionality in OpenSuse. However, by default every variation of `su` or `sudo` that I have tried sets the `HOME` env var to the target user's value.

Can anyone give me the precise steps for implementing one variation (I.e., an alias or something) of either `su` or `sudo` that will do the following:

- preserve the original user's `HOME` env var
- combine the original user's `PATH` env var with the target user's `PATH` env var
- otherwise, work similarly to `sudo -s` in Ubuntu or `su` in OpenSuse.

I prefer to change as little about the default config as possible, and I would hope to come up with a script that will implement this minor change so that when I upgrade, I can restore my configuration with minimal disruption/effort.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables - note that changes you make to these configuration files will not be overwritten with an upgrade, you will be prompted to keep, lose or merge any changes

Comment: @Paul - yes, I know that. But experience tells me that this is not a good thing to do very often. Or, stated another way, I don't want to change files that cause me to have to merge config files during an upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass environment variables through to the sudo environment on the command line:

```
sudo env HOME=$HOME PATH=$PATH <command>
```

Because the variable substitutions happen first, the current versions of the variables are substituted on the command line, and then run with the `env` command in the new environment, and then `<command>` is executed.

This doesn't meet your second critiria for combining paths however, but you could wrap this in a script, and pass exactly the path you want into the `sudo` environment.  System level paths don't change that much, especially given your approach of leaving as much vanilla as possible.  So in your script, you could set up a new path variable and then go to sudo:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH2=$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin
sudo env PATH=$PATH2 HOME=$HOME $@
```

Call this 'mysudo' perhaps and you could even alias `sudo` to `mysudo` in your bash profile so that your muscle memory for typing `sudo` still works.

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting and very helpful. How can I use that with "sudo -s" or similar variant where I want a root shell (rather than just executing a single command)?

Comment: You could do this using `sudo env HOME=$HOME bash`- so invoke a bash shell via sudo passing in the varaibles needed.