# Setting up PostgreSQL gives error sudo: initdb: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql

Step 1: I installed PostgreSQL using `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1` as recommended on the PostgreSQL website

Step 2: I tried to run `postgres`. It's not found. For whatever reason, the install doesn't appear to add it to the path? So I had to manually add the line `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin` to the bottom of my `~/.profile`. (Sidenote: Anybody know why this is necessary? Am I doing something wrong with the install? Everything else I've installed in Ubuntu "just works" without changing the `$PATH`...)

Step 3: I try running `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`. Permission denied. I try running `sudo initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`. Result is `sudo: initdb: command not found`. How is this command not found? I just ran the damn thing! `echo sudo $PATH` shows the PostgreSQL directory in the path... what am I missing?

I'm a bit of a newbie in Linux, but these are the sorts of super-irritating problems I keep running into!

**UPDATE**: I believe it's related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/259382/how-does-sudo-search-the-path-for-executables). However, running the command with `sudo -i` does *not* fix the problem. I just get: `-bash: initdb: command not found`. Great.

**UPDATE**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why) seems even closer. So I added `alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'` to my `.bashrc` as instructed. Still doesn't effin' work! It looks like the alias isn't working. When I run `alias`, I only show a single one. And yet my `.bashrc` is full of them... so something is wrong with those getting set up.

**UPDATE**: Since I'm using Ubuntu and RVM, RVM recommended that I set up the terminal to "Run command as login shell". Based on reading I did [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132276/configure-gnome-terminal-to-start-bash-as-a-login-shell-doesnt-read-bashrc), it seems that the `.bashrc` file isn't read in a login shell, only profile. So I moved the `alias` line from `.bashrc` to `.profile`, so `.profile` now has this at the end:

```
export PATH="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin:$PATH"
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

... and it still doesn't work. Running `alias` only shows an RVM alias, but not the `sudo` alias I tried to set up.

**UPDATE** From [this site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DotFiles), I read about the precedence of dotfiles. It looks like `.bash_profile` comes before `.profile`. That being said, my `PATH` additions were done in `.profile`, and seemed to be loaded just fine, so why wasn't the `alias` also working? Moving the `alias` into `.bash_profile` from `.profile` worked, however. Mystery. So then the `alias` command shows my new alias. I finally type in `sudo initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`, to be met with: `initdb: cannot be run as root`. Oh, really? Then why were you giving me **permission errors**?! So now I think the problem is that I just have to `chown` the folder, but still run `initdb` as my user rather than `root`.

**UPDATE** Running the command `sudo chown myuser /usr/local/var/postgres/`, and then running `initdb` afterward allowed the database to be initialized. Glad it was so obvious that the directory permissions needed to be set to myuser and not root. Incredible. Successful database init 4 hours later.

Answer (score 10):

Once you've installed the PostgreSQL server with `apt-get install postgresql-9.1`, it's already set up and running so your steps #2 and #3 (run `postgres` and run `initdb`) are not necessary and in fact would conflict with what has already been set up. By running manually `initdb` you'll end up with two postgres clusters.

The postgresql packages for Debian and Ubuntu provide a command named [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) that resides in `/usr/bin` and that you may call, should you need to create a new cluster. Under the hood, this command will call `initdb` with the right parameters. The end user is not supposed to call `initdb` directly, which is why it's not in the normal PATH.
There are also other commands like [pg_dropcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_dropcluster.8.html) and [pg_ctlcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) that supersede the ways a non-packaged PostgreSQL instance would be administrated.

All this is meant for the packaging system to handle and upgrade automatically the clusters, which are features that the baseline PostgreSQL leaves to the database administrator.

Comment: I came to this thread because I want to initiate postgresql data directories in a custom location after updating relevant directories in the `/etc/posgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf`.

There are use cases, such as mine, where one needs to run `initdb`.

Answer (score 8):

When you run sudo it is best to put the full path to the command you are running.  In your instance:

```
sudo /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Comment: I'm sure that will work, but why am I the only person having this problem? None of the tutorials or sites I'm looking at tell you to preface the command with the entire path.

Comment: When you run sudo it reads the setting set in the sudoers file.  There are several setting related to environment and if it should be reset or maintained.  This post speaks about maintaining the environment, http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with an Amazon Web Services instance.  The Postgresql site assumes you have the server and client installed.

`sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgresql-devel postgresql-contrib postgresql-docs`

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely that initdb was not installed into a `$PATH` location. Check your paths (where the system looks for executables)

Command:

```
echo $PATH
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

To find where `initdb` was installed, you can just look for it directly

Command:

```
find / -name initdb
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb /usr/local/bin/
```

You have two choices in this case. Either add the postgres directory to `$PATH` or do a `mv` into one of the locations listed in `$PATH`

```
 mv /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb /usr/local/bin/
```

As a result, `initdb` should give you some kind of output.

```
 initdb
 initdb: no data directory specified
 You must identify the directory where the data for this database system
 will reside.  Do this with either the invocation option -D or the
 environment variable PGDATA.
```

Make sure to move the `Postgres` binary into the same location as `initdb`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make a symbolic link to a path known by the environment, e.g:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/initdb /usr/local/bin/
```