# sudo -E not passing all variables

Tags: bash, environment-variables, sudo

Reading the `man pages` I expected `sudo -E` to pass all environment variables to the subshell, but I am not getting the expected results.

As expected, awesome:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mmendez/toolchains/x86-destdir/usr/lib/
$ env | grep LD
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mmendez/toolchains/x86-destdir/usr/lib/
```

More awesomeness:

```
$ env -i LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/no/where env | grep LD
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/no/where
```

Not what was expected:

```
$ env -i LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH sudo -E /usr/bin/env | grep LD
$
$ env -i LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/no/where sudo -E /usr/bin/env | grep LD
$
```

So, how can I get `sudo -E` to pass `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, **without** editing `/etc/sudoers`?

**Edit**:

According to 
[How do I make sudo preserve my environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables) the OP indicates that the shell may play a role in conjunction with `!env_reset`. I am running `Arch Linux` and the default shell is `BASH`. Once again, I do **not** want to edit `/etc/sudoers`, is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Certain environment variables, including `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `HOSTALIASES` (full list is in [sysdeps/generic/unsecvars.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/generic/unsecvars.h;h=d5b8119c9cb5cf5f1391325282287c5935c86589;hb=HEAD)), are automatically unset by glibc when executing a privileged program (i.e. with the *setuid* bit or with filesystem capabilities). This is a security feature, since otherwise users could load their own libraries into `su` or `sudo` and trick them into accepting any password.

You will need to use `sudo env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH yourcommand` in order to pass the variable to commands run via sudo.