# sudo not able to access private key

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have a public-private key pair at `~/.ssh` being used for SSH connection to GitHub.

In order to test if I've setup SSH with GitHub properly, I used `ssh -T git@github.com`, which works fine.

Also, If I execute the above command as superuser, it works fine.

```
su
ssh -T git@github.com
```

However, when I use sudo, the command isn't working. I suspect it's not able to access the key pair stored at `~/.ssh` when run with `sudo`

The command below fails.

`sudo ssh -T git@github.com`

You can easily replicate the issue with any Ubuntu distribution and [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) GitHub help page.

**Edit** :

I understand that I can pass the private key to `ssh` as follows:

`ssh -i <path-to-private-key> -T git@github.com`

I'm just wondering why using `sudo ssh -T git@github.com` makes the private key inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis: there's an authentication agent running for your regular user and the agent holds the key.

`ssh` spawned from a non-elevated shell inherits the crucial environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` that tells it the location of the socket to communicate with the agent. `ssh` is able to use the agent, this is how you normally use an agent.

`su` does not unset the variable. `ssh` after `su` is able to locate the socket thanks to the variable. Normally the socket cannot be accessed by users other than the owner, but now `ssh` runs as root and root can access (almost) any file regardless of its permissions.

`sudo` *does* unset the variable (by default; see [this](https://superuser.com/q/232231/432690) and [that](https://superuser.com/a/1446167/432690)). `ssh` in `sudo ssh …` is not able to locate the socket. It's like the agent wasn't there. `ssh` tries to find the right private key in few default locations in `~/.ssh`, but now it checks in the root's home directory, not in your regular user's home directory where the right private key is.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the path to your identity file with the -i option to ssh.

```
ssh user@host -i /path/to/keyfile
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I'm just wondering why using `sudo` makes the private key inaccessible.