# sudo and environment variables acting differently in Debian vs. Ubuntu

Tags: linux, sudo

So, this is something I can't wrap my head around. I know how to configure `sudo` to keep all envs intact, I'm now baffled what causes the different behaviour on Ubuntu vs. Debian.

So in Debian I have the sudoers configured with

```
~# cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I set some variables at `/etc/environment`, re-login and test:

```
~# sudo sh -c 'echo $FOO'
```

The environment is not there, as it shouldn't (AFAIK at least) as the sudoers is configured to reset the env.

Doing the same stuff on Ubuntu:

```
~# cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Note: It has the same `env_reset` set. But:

```
~# sudo sh -c 'echo $FOO'
bar
```

So the question that baffles me is: Why this works on Ubuntu even when the `env_reset` is set and neither my Ubuntu or Debian config has any `env_keep` set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man 5 sudoers` says:

> By default, the `env_reset` option is enabled. This causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment.  On AIX (and Linux systems without PAM), the environment is initialized with the contents of the `/etc/environment` file.

So [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM) is important. Let's check `/etc/pam.d/sudo` on both systems. This line is there on Ubuntu but *not* on Debian:

```
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
```

Then this is what `man 8 pam_env` says:

> This module can also parse a file with simple `KEY=VAL` pairs on separate lines (`/etc/environment` by default). You can change the default file to parse, with the `envfile` flag and turn it on or off by setting the `readenv` flag to `1` or `0` respectively.

It looks like `readenv=1` in this very line is responsible for parsing `/etc/environment` when `sudo` runs. Indeed, setting this to `0` (or commenting the entire line out) makes `sudo sh -c 'echo $FOO'` in my Ubuntu behave like in Debian.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I wasn't thinking about PAMs involvement in the env part at all. The explanation you provided is spot on, thanks for that.