# ssh tunneling public key error

Tags: linux, ssh, port-forwarding, tunnel

I'm trying to setup ssh port tunneling. I am setup with my public key on the remote machine. I can login to the remote like this...

```
ssh <name>@<address>
```

No problem.

I'm trying to forward my port 80 into the remote machine like this...

```
sudo ssh -N -L 80:localhost:80 <name>@<address>
```

This gives the following error...

```
<name>@<address>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*

```
sudo ssh -v <name>@<address>
```

gives...

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <address> [<address>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <address>:22 as '<name>'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Pwr+uZp+l1Wmg0SWOtc71zk5Z07Di39xdCrsJ0do3v0
debug1: Host '<address>' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
<name>@<address>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show what happens when you run `sudo ssh -v <name>@<address>`. I think with `sudo`, `ssh` uses the private key from `root`'s home directory not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa` is the… key. We can see that `ssh` in `sudo ssh …` tries to use root's private keys, not your regular user's private keys.

An authentication agent [probably wouldn't make any difference](https://superuser.com/a/1746418/432690).

Tell your elevated `ssh` to use *your* key. Example:

```
sudo ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -N -L 80:localhost:80 <name>@<address>
```

Note `~/.ssh/id_rsa` in the above command points to your key because your non-elevated shell expands `~` before `sudo` is started. You can use `"$HOME"/.ssh/id_rsa` and the situation will be the same.

The elevated `ssh` should be able to read your key because [root can access any file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117150/108618) (well, almost; e.g. if your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is provided by FUSE then root may or may not be able to access it ([example](https://superuser.com/a/1531417/432690)); I assume this is not the case).

Comment: That did it, thanks mate.