# How to set environment variables with sudo -u USER?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo

Hello and sorry for my English in advance.

I need to execute from **root** command like

```
envVariable1=15 envVariable2=25 sudo -u user1 sudo -E myCommand
```

but environment variables don't pass to myCommand. This may look illogical, but it's necessary to run command from **root** and with **sudo** cause it will be used in scripts.
How can I work around the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make sudo preserve my environment variables?](http://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables)

Comment: Why the double `sudo`? What's wrong with `envVariable1=15 envVariable2=25 sudo -E myCommand`? If there's a good reason for the the first `sudo`, this also needs a `-E`. Alternatively, if you don't need to preserve other environment variables, add an `env` command to the final `sudo`, as in `sudo -u user1 sudo env envVariable1=15 envVariable2=25 myCommand`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should type `var1=1 var2=2 sudo -E -u user1 sudo -E myCommand` and then **var1** and **var2** will be available for user1.

Thanks to **AFH** to help me to find an answer!