# How can I keep my environment variable when doing sudo? (csh, CentOS)

Tags: centos, path, environment-variables, sudo

I have read  [How do I make sudo preserve my environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/232231/how-do-i-make-sudo-preserve-my-environment-variables) and I have the lines below in my /etc/sudoers file.

```
Defaults        env_reset
.....
Defaults        env_keep += "PATH"
```

but my PATH variable is different when I'm doing sudo as shown below.

```
ckim@stph45:~/testsocket] printenv PATH
/home/ckim/Neuro/py-faster-rcnn/caffe-fast-rcnn/.build_debug/tools/:/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib:/home/ckim/anaconda2/bin:/home/ckim/uClinux/sparc-uclinux-3.4.4/bin:/opt/abde-rtems/bin:/opt/abde/bin:/opt/abocd/bin:/usr/lib64/qt4/bin:/home1/vivado-2014.3.1/DocNav:/home1/vivado-2014.3.1/Vivado/2014.3.1/bin:.:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/Acrobat7.0/bin:/home1/cadence/installs/INCISIV152/tools/bin:/home1/cadence/installs/INCISIV152/tools/bin/64bit:/home1/cadence/installs/INCISIV152/tools.lnx86/bin/64bit:/home1/ise132/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64:/home1/ise132/ISE_DS/ISE/synopsys:/home1/ise132/ISE_DS/PlanAhead/bin:/home1/ise132/ISE_DS/ChipScope/bin/lin64:/home/ckim/bin
ckim@stph45:~/testsocket] sudo printenv PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

What can be wrong? I'm doing it on tcsh on CentOS 6.7 (Final).

EDIT (question changed) : (thanks to quixotic) After adding "." to secure_path in sudoers file, the secure_path is in effect so I can let it find my executable in the current directory, but it gives me this error.

```
ckim@stph45:~/testsocket] sudo TCPEchoServer 7
sudo: ignoring `TCPEchoServer' found in '.'
Use `sudo ./TCPEchoServer' if this is the `TCPEchoServer' you wish to run
```

How can I make the shell not ignore "." in secure_path? I don't want to put './executable', that's why I started this question.

Comment: note the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/232258/685512) on that question and its discussion of sudo's `secure_path`.  also note the full comments below, including [another duplicate](http://serverfault.com/a/541880) on serverfault.

Comment: ok, I thought having PATH in the env_keep is supposed to do the trick. Anyway, I added "." in the secure_path, becaue I wanted to exeucte a file in current directory where every that may be. After adding "." to the secure_path, it gives me different error. I'll modify my question then. Thanks.